# Inserting image into visualforce email template (without hard-coding IDs)

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

The "official" solution for including images in visualforce email templates suggests hard coding IDs in your template to reference an image file stored as a document.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_template_images.htm&language=en_US

Is there a better way that avoids hard coding instance ID and OID?  I tried using the partner URL to grab the instance ID, but I got the following error

Error   Error: The reference to entity "oid" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Using:
{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140,FIND(".com/",$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)/

to replace "https://na2.salesforce.com/"

in

"na2.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01540000000RVOe&oid=00Dxxxxxxxxx&lastMod=1233217920"

Should I use a static resource instead?

Answer (score 2):

I've arrived here looking for an answer for this question related to hardcoded ID and OID in Visualforce e-mail templates. Well, I found a workaround for that.

First I needed to create a Visualforce Component:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="LogomarcaController">
    <apex:image url="{!LogoUrl}" />
</apex:component>
```

In the respective controller class, I've created a *SFInstance* property to get the correct URL Salesforce Instance, *LogoUrl* property to concatenate SFInstance and IDs... And Finally I've used Custom Settings (*Config_Gerais__c.getInstance().ID_Documento_Logomarca__c*) to configurate the ID of Image (in my case, Document Object) on Sandbox or Production:

```
public class LogomarcaController {
public String LogoUrl {
    get {
        id orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        String idDocumentoLogomarca = Config_Gerais__c.getInstance().ID_Documento_Logomarca__c;
        return this.SfInstance + '/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=' + idDocumentoLogomarca  + '&oid=' + orgId ;
    }
}

public String SfInstance
{
    get{
        string SFInstance = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
        list<string> Dividido = SFInstance.split('.visual', 0);//retira o restante a partir de .visual
        SFInstance = dividido[0];
        dividido = SFInstance.split('://',0);//retira o https://
        SFInstance = dividido[1];
        if(!SFInstance.contains('sybf')) //managed package prefix, if you need
        {
           SFInstance = 'sybf.'+  SFInstance;
        }
        return 'https://'+SFInstance;
    }
}
}
```

And finally, I've added the component in Visualforce template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Novo Ofício - {!relatedTo.name}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Oficio__c" >
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >

    <c:Logomarca />

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

PS: Some of my variables, properties and comments are in my native language (portuguese). If you have some problems understanding them, please ask me!

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar problem and after trying various solutions, the following worked for us. In our case the image is uploaded as a content asset(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320130&type=1&language=en_US&mode=1)

Solution:

```html
<img src="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260,FIND('/services',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))}/file-asset-public/<Image_Name_Here>?oid={!$Organization.Id}&height=50&width=50"/>
```